# Ticket Price Calculation

Tags: java, class, static

Create a class Ticket with the following private variables

```
int ticketid;
int price;
static int `availableTickets`;
```

Include getters and setters methods in the Ticket class.
Available Tickets should hold only positive value. Zero and negative values are not allowed.(This logic should be checked inside the corresponding setter method)
Write the following method in the Ticket class:

```
public int calculateTicketCost(int no_of_tickets)
```

— this method should check the ticket availability, if the tickets are available, reduce the `no_of_tickets` from `available_Tickets` and calculate the total amount as `nooftickets*price` and return the total amount. If the tickets are not available, this method should return -1.
Write a main method in the Main class to test the application.

Sample input and output

```
Enter no of bookings:
2
Enter the available tickets:
25
Enter the ticket id:
123
Enter the price:
100
Enter the no of tickets:
5
Available tickets: 25
Total amount:500
Available ticket after booking:20
Enter the ticket id:
124
Enter the price:
100
Enter the no of tickets:
2
Available tickets: 20
Total amount:200
Available ticket after booking:18
```

Comment: Looks like HW..  what have you done so far? show your code

Comment: read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Abhinav.

Answer (score 4):

Ticket.java

```
public class Ticket{
private int ticketid;
private int price;
private static int availableTickets;

public void setTicketid(int ticket) //setter
{
    ticketid = ticket;
}
public int getTicketid() //getter
{
    return ticketid;
}


public int getPrice() //getter
{                       
    return price; 
}
public void setPrice(int prc) //setter
{
    price = prc;
    
}

public static int getAvailableTickets() //getter
{                  
        return availableTickets;
}
public static void setAvailableTickets(int availTicket) //setter
{
    if(availTicket > 0)
        availableTickets = availTicket;
}

public int calculateTicketCost(int nooftickets)//Check ticket availability
{
    int tik = getAvailableTickets();
    if(nooftickets > tik)
        return -1;
    
 
    tik -=  nooftickets;
    setAvailableTickets(tik);
    return price * nooftickets;
    
}
```

}

Main.java

```
import java.util.*;
```

public class Main{

```
public static void main (String[] args) {
    
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    Ticket t = new Ticket();
    
    System.out.println("Enter no of bookings:\n");
    int no = s.nextInt();
    
    System.out.println("\nEnter the available tickets:\n");
    int availableTicket = s.nextInt();
    t.setAvailableTickets(availableTicket);
    
    do{
        
    System.out.println("\nEnter the ticketid:\n");
    int tickedId = s.nextInt();
    t.setTicketid(tickedId);
    
    System.out.println("\nEnter the price:\n");
    int price = s.nextInt();
    t.setPrice(price);
    
    System.out.println("\nEnter the no of tickets:\n");
    int bookTickets = s.nextInt();
    
    System.out.println("\nAvailable tickets:"+t.getAvailableTickets());
    System.out.println("\nTotal amount:"+t.calculateTicketCost(bookTickets));
    System.out.println("\nAvailable ticket after booking:"+t.getAvailableTickets());
    
    no--;
    }while(no>0);
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Do the main class at least

```
public void setAvaiableTicket(int count) {
    availableTickets = count > 0 ? count : 1;
}

public int calculateTicketCost(int no_of_tickets) {
    if (no_of_tickets > availableTickets) return -1;
    availableTickets -= no_of_tickets;
    return price * no_of_tickets;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ticket.java

```
public class Ticket{
private int ticketid;
private int price;
private static int availableTickets;

public void setTicketid(int a){
    ticketid=a;
}
public void setPrice(int a){
    price=a;
}
public static void setAvailableTickets(int count) {
if(count > 0)
availableTickets=count;
}

public int getTicketid(){
    return ticketid;
}
public int getPrice(){
    return price;
}
public static int getAvailableTickets(){
    return availableTickets;
}
public int calculateTicketCost(int nooftickets) {
if (nooftickets > availableTickets) 
    return -1;
availableTickets -= nooftickets;
return price * nooftickets;
}   


}
```

Main.java

```
import java.util.*;
public class Main{
public static void main (String[] args) {
    /* code */

    Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
    Ticket t=new Ticket();
    System.out.println("Enter no of bookings:");
    int no=sc.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Enter the available tickets:");
    int avail=sc.nextInt();
    t.setAvailableTickets(avail);
    while(no>0){
    System.out.println("Enter the ticketid:");
    int id=sc.nextInt();
    t.setTicketid(id);
    System.out.println("Enter the price:");
    int price=sc.nextInt();
    t.setPrice(price);
    System.out.println("Enter the no of tickets:");
    int notick=sc.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Available tickets:"+t.getAvailableTickets());
    System.out.println("Total amount:" + t.calculateTicketCost(notick));
    System.out.println("Available ticket after booking:" + t.getAvailableTickets());
    
    no--;
    }

}
}
```